# What "It" Said on the Golden Ticket

Tags: grammar

I had a question regarding the use of "it" in this chapter title from "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory." What exactly is "it" referring to? The information? Why does it need to be phrased this way and are there any other examples of when "it" is used similarly? Any insight it much appreciated!

Comment: Is "it" in quotes in the chapter title?

Comment: @cruthers - It's been a while since I've read the book, but I'm nigh-certain it does not.  The asker is using quotes simply to focus attention on the word that confuses him.

Answer (score 3):

Here, "it" is what is known as a "dummy subject", "empty it", or "ambient it".  It doesn't exactly refer to anything, but performs a grammatical function.  I mean, you could view this it as referring to the Golden Ticket, but the Golden Ticket is mentioned later anyway, so it doesn't really.

We use this construction in many circumstances.  Focusing on just the form you are asking about, we can show pairs of sentences that basically have the same meaning:

> What does the Golden Ticket say?
> What does it say on the Golden Ticket?

> What does the sign say?
> What does it say on the sign?

> What does the book say?
> What does it say in the book?

And when the context is clear, we can even drop the "on the/in the..." portion!  We can simply say:

> What does it say?

Why use the dummy subject instead of being more direct?  It can be personal choice, or it can be about focusing the sentence more on the words than the object the words are in.  The thing mentioned earlier in the sentence gets more focus, so "What does the Golden Ticket say" places more focus on the Golden Ticket, while "What does it say on the Golden Ticket" instead places the focus on the words themselves, not the ticket.

The dummy subject is also used in other sentences you may be more familiar with:

> It is hot.
> It is rainy.
> It is late.
> It is time to go.

Again, you could stretch things and say that "it" refers to the weather in general, or the time, or the situation, but really, these "it"s are grammatical placeholders.

Comment: In this example "it" refers to the writing on the Golden Ticket. Non-language context can be very important, as in "it is hot" when I have taken a mouthful of food, or when I am fanning myself outside.

Comment: Yes, you *can* think of it that way, as I said.  But grammarians say that these "it"s are placeholders, and I see their point.  Look up "dummy subject" or "empty it" and you'll see.